# Accessing to return value of a thread by another one other than creating one

Tags: c, multithreading, concurrency

Why have `copyfilepass` return a pointer to the number of bytes copied when `callcopypass` can access this value as `args[2]`?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include "restart.h"

void *copyfilepass(void *arg)  {
   int *argint;

   argint = (int *)arg;
   /* copyfile copies from a descriptor to another */
   argint[2] = copyfile(argint[0], argint[1]);
   close(argint[0]);
   close(argint[1]);
   return argint + 2;
}
```

callcopypass.c

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#define PERMS (S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR)
#define READ_FLAGS O_RDONLY
#define WRITE_FLAGS (O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC)
void *copyfilepass(void *arg);

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
   int *bytesptr;
   int error;
   int targs[3];
   pthread_t tid;

   if (argc != 3) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s fromfile tofile\n", argv[0]);
      return 1;
   }

   if (((targs[0] = open(argv[1], READ_FLAGS)) == -1) ||
       ((targs[1] = open(argv[2], WRITE_FLAGS, PERMS)) == -1)) {
      perror("Failed to  open the files");
      return 1;
   }
   if (error = pthread_create(&tid, NULL, copyfilepass, targs)) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create thread: %s\n", strerror(error));
      return 1;
   }
   if (error = pthread_join(tid, (void **)&bytesptr)) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Failed to join thread: %s\n", strerror(error));
      return 1;
   }
   printf("Number of bytes copied: %d\n", *bytesptr);
   return 0;
}
```

The authors answer that

> if a thread other than the creating thread joins with `copyfilepass`, it
>   has access to the number of bytes copied through the parameter to
>   `pthread_join`.

I don't even comprehend the answer. How another thread can access the return value (i.e. change the value?) other than creating one? Could you explain it if possible with an example?

Comment: You don't have to call `pthread_join` from the same thread that called `pthread_create`.

Comment: If you want another thread to have access to some variable then make it shared, then imply some locking to prevent race conditions.

Comment: "Why have copyfilepass return a pointer ...?" What else du you suggest to return?

Answer (score 2):

The crux of the answer is that you could foreseeably want to read the result of the `copyfilepass` thread (in this case the number of bytes copied) from a thread other than the thread which created it. Assume, for the sake of example, we have a third thread, `monitorcopy`, and `tid` is a global instead of a local variable. `monitorcopy` is spawned after `copyfilepass` from the main method.

```
void* monitorcopy(void* params) {
  void *result
  pthread_join(tid, &result);
  /* Point A: Attempt to read result */
}
```

Assume `copyfilepass` returned `NULL`, or a meaningless value. At Point A, `result` is `NULL` and we have no way of retrieving the number of bytes copied, as it is stored in `targs[2]` in the main method, which is out of scope.

Assume instead `copyfilepass` returned `argint + 2`. `result` is now a pointer to the number of bytes copied, even though we are not in the same scope as `targs`. Thus, in the absence of any memory lifetime issues, we can access the number of bytes copied as follows:

```
void* monitorcopy(void* params) {
  void *result
  pthread_join(tid, &result);
  int bytesCopied = *((int*) result);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't that a different thread would want to "change the return value", it's whether a different thread will have access to the *input* parameters (`targs`). Generally, `pthread_join` allows you to get the **result** value from a certain thread, from any place in your program, as long as you have the thread id. So isn't it sensible to use this value to return the result of the async operation?

However, this example is rather poorly written (as an example for good multithreading practices), for a number of reasons:

1. There is only a single function, and the scope of all variables extends through `main`. Written this way, **everyone has access to the input args** anyway. You are right when you say that reading the result through `pthread_join` is unnecessary in this case.
2. Passing a stack variable (`targs`) to a thread is a **bad idea**. The variable will go out of scope when the function ends, so the only safe way for the program not to crash is to join the thread immediatelly, preventing `targs` from going out of scope. Which means you don't get any benefits of multithreading (unless `main` does some extra work before joining). They should be either made global, or allocated on the heap (a `malloc`/`free` pair).
3. Files are opened inside `main`, but closed inside `copyfilepass`. This shift of responsibility is unnecessary, although not uncommon. I would either pass the file names to the function and handle the opening there, or close the handles outside the thread, after the files are copied.

Anyway, the point that author of the code had was that you don't need to have access to the input arguments at the place where you're joining the thread:

```
// removed all error checks for simplicity
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

   pthread_t tid;    

   // removed all error checks for simplicity
   pthread_create(&tid, NULL, copy_file, argv);

   // note that this function only accepts the thread id
   wait_until_copied(tid);

   return 0;
}

void wait_until_copied(pthread_t tid)
{
    int *bytesptr;
    // no way to access input args here
    pthread_join(tid, (void **)&bytesptr);
    printf("Number of bytes copied: %d\n", *bytesptr);
}
```

Comment: I feel like inheriting from you the golden points :) I get exactly what it means. However, in your code exapmle, is there a guarantee that `copy_file` returns after `wait_until_copied`? I think no. I'd just like to verify I understand how threads work. If thread routine returns first, it doesn't release its sources until seen `pthread_join(...)` or  `pthread_exit(...)` or `pthread_detach(...)`. If `wait_until_copied` is on run, when `pthread_join(...)` line is seen, it blocks until the thread routine is completed?

Comment: `pthread_join` guarantees that it will block until the thread has ended. If the thread has already finished at this point, then it will just return immediately. Also, the thread doesn't release any its resources unless you explicitly call `pthread_join` or `pthread_detach` (although calling the latter while the thread is running won't do anything, so you might as well forget about it). So the thing that you need to do is: 1) provide a long-enough lifetime (scope) of your thread input parameters, and 2) call `pthread_join` to get the result and cleanup.